# How to solve Undefined offset: 5 in /~/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3284 in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

**Error**

Undefined offset: 5 in /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3284

'posts_per_page' is set 5 to take 5 posts.

I don't understand why this 5 brings this error.

---

**Current Code**

```php
function queryPopularPosts() {
    return new WP_Query(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 5
        )
    );
}

function displayPopularPosts() {
    $query = queryPopularPosts();
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();
                echo '<p>'.the_title().'</p>';
            }
    }
}
```

---

**/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3284**

```php
public function next_post() {

        $this->current_post++;

        $this->post = $this->posts[ $this->current_post ]; //3284
        return $this->post;
    }
```

**the_post() in /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php**

```php
public function the_post() {
        global $post;
        $this->in_the_loop = true;

        if ( -1 == $this->current_post ) { // Loop has just started.
            /**
             * Fires once the loop is started.
             *
             * @since 2.0.0
             *
             * @param WP_Query $this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
             */
            do_action_ref_array( 'loop_start', array( &$this ) );
        }

        $post = $this->next_post();
        $this->setup_postdata( $post );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Array keys usually start at 0. Perhaps try `$this->post = $this->posts[ $this->current_post - 1 ]; //3284` instead?